# I want to open the hot spot using flutter for android

Tags: flutter, hotspot

How to use [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot)  flutter plugin, because i can't find it's docs
because i want to open the mobile hotspot and set it's credentials with flutter

Comment: Well the docs are right at the link you provided. Maybe check again how to ask questions successfully on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: thanks, but when I use any function from the package it says that is deprecated